# Derivation of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Evaluate
>   $$\large\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{\large\int_0^{e^x}{\cos (s)\,\mathrm  ds}}\sec(t^2)\,\mathrm dt$$

I got the answer to be $$e^x\cdot\sec(\sin^2(e^x))\cdot \cos(e^x)$$ but do not know if this is correct and if not some suggestions?

Comment: You're correct, despite writing $e^x$ instead of $\exp x$ in an upper limit of an integral that's in the upper limit of *another* integral. ;)

Comment: So I need to replace the e^x with something else?

Comment: No, no.  Just busting your chops on typesetting preferences.  Everything looks good.

Comment: Okay, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider first $$F(x)=\int_0^{a(x)}f(t)dt$$ The fundamental theorem of calculus says that $$\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{a(x)}f(t)dt=f\big(a(x)\big) a'(x)$$ So, for the case considered here $$a(x)=\int_0^{e^x}\cos(s)ds=\sin \left(e^x\right)$$ $$a'(x)=e^x \cos \left(e^x\right)$$ and since $$f(t)=\sec(t^2)$$ combining all pieces lead to $$\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=e^x \cos \left(e^x\right) \sec \left(\sin ^2\left(e^x\right)\right)$$ which is identical to the answer given in the post.

Answer (score 1):

It is

$$ [ \tan(\int_0^{e^{x^2}}\cos sds)]' =  [ \tan(\sin e^{x^2})]'$$

> $$\sec^2(\sin e^{x^2})  \cdot \cos e^{x^2}  \cdot e^{x^2} \cdot  (2x)  $$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I do not understand how you got to this stage?

Comment: This isn't right, as the integral is not of $\sec^2 t$ but of $\sec t^2$

Comment: So this is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Take $f'(t)=\sec(t^2)$ and $g'(s)=\cos(s)$. Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{\large\int_0^{e^x}{\cos (s)\,\mathrm  ds}}\sec(t^2)\,\mathrm dt=\frac{d}{dx}{\int_0^{\large\int_0^{e^x}g'(s)\,\mathrm ds}}f'(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{g(e^x)-g(0)}f'(t)\mathrm \,dt=\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\,(g(e^x)-g(0)\,)-f(0)\,\right)$$
$$=f'(g(e^x)-g(0))g'(e^x)e^x=\sec(\sin^2(e^x))\cos(e^x)e^x$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{\int_0^{e^x}\cos(s)ds} \sec(t^2)dt=\sec(\sin^2e^x)\frac{d}{dx}{\sin^2e^x}=\sec(\sin^2e^x).(\sin2e^x)e^x$$